# SQL group by not working (from 3 queries)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have three queries, I already created another query in which I combined the three queries. 
The queries are:

```
with tbl1 as(
    SELECT coachEID,role,coacheeEID, 
    IIF(count(status)>IIF(a.role='SME',1,2),IIF(a.role='SME',1,2),count(status))
    AS total from coaching z
    JOIN tbl_calendar v
    ON z.starttime BETWEEN v.datestart and v.dateend
    JOIN roster a on z.coachEID=a.EID
    WHERE z.status='completed'
    AND v.month='1' and v.year='2017'
    AND a.location='manila'
GROUP BY  coacheid, coacheeeid, status, role),

tbl2 as(
    SELECT y.role, y.eid, x.eid as coachee, IIF(y.eid=x.sme,1,2) AS target
    FROM roster y
    JOIN roster x ON (x.supervisor = y.eid OR x.sme = y.eid OR x.teamlead = y.eid)  AND x.eid <> y.eid 
    AND x.employstatus = 'Active'
    WHERE y.employstatus = 'active' 
    AND y.Role IN ('SME', 'Junior Team Lead','Team Lead', 'Shift Lead', 'Operations Lead', 'Quality Lead', 'Policy Lead') 
    AND y.location = 'manila'),

tbl3 as(
    SELECT x.coachEID,x.CoacheeEID,  sum (x.NoOfApproved) as exempt, x.month, x.year from exemptitems x
    LEFT JOIN roster y on y.eid=x.Coacheid
    WHERE x.month='1' and x.year='2017'
    AND y.eid=x.coacheid and x.NoOfApproved is not NULL
    GROUP BY x.CoachEID, x.CoacheeEID, x.Month, x.year)
```

Final query is:

```
select IIF(tbl2.role is NULL, tbl1.role,tbl2.role) as role, 
       IIF(tbl1.coachEID is NULL,tbl2.eid,tbl1.coachEID) as coacheid,
       IIF(tbl1.coacheeEID is NULL, tbl2.coachee,tbl1.coacheeEID) as coacheeeid, 
       IIF(total is NULL,0,total) as total,
       IIF(tbl2.target is NUll,total,tbl2.target) as ttarget,
       IIF(tbl3.exempt is NULL,0,tbl3.exempt) as texemption, 
       IIF(tbl2.target is NULL,total,tbl2.target)-IIF(tbl3.exempt is NULL,0,tbl3.exempt) as ttotal
from tbl1
FULL join tbl2  
  on tbl1.coachEID=tbl2.eid and tbl1.coacheeEID=tbl2.coachee
left JOIN tbl3 
  on tbl1.coachEID=tbl3.CoachEID
```

[image: query result]

My question is, what method should I use to have it in group? I already tried group by but it's not working. I wanted it to group by role, coacheid and their total coaching (total column). Whenever I try to use GROUP BY role,coacheid, coacheeeid on the end statement of the final query, all I get was "Ambiguous column name 'role'" and "Ambiguous column name 'coacheid'"

Comment: Not working - how? Syntax error, other error, or unexpected result? Show us your GROUP BY attempt.

Comment: First up, what's wrong with `coalesce`? Second, group by what? Each row appears distinct already...

Comment: can you share sample db if possible or sql fiddle and also can you brief for about the required output ?

Comment: I already done editing my code, ls see above. thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'Ambiguous column name' means, you forgot to specify table name in front of the column. Choose one and put it there (`GROUP BY`).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the help. I already figured out how is it done. Here's my full code:

```
with tbl1 as(
   SELECT coachEID,role,coacheeEID,
   IIF(count(status)>IIF(a.role='SME',1,2),
   IIF(a.role='SME',1,2),count(status))
AS total from coaching z
 JOIN tbl_calendar v
ON z.starttime BETWEEN v.datestart and v.dateend
 JOIN roster a on z.coachEID=a.EID
WHERE z.status='completed'
AND v.month='1' and v.year='2017'
AND a.location='manila'
AND a.Role IN ('SME', 'Junior Team Lead','Team Lead', 'Shift Lead', 'Operations Lead', 'Quality Lead', 'Policy Lead') 
GROUP BY coacheid, coacheeeid, status, role),

tbl2 as(
   SELECT y.role, y.eid, x.eid as coachee, IIF(y.eid=x.sme,1,2) AS target
   FROM roster y
JOIN roster x ON (x.supervisor = y.eid OR x.sme = y.eid OR x.teamlead = y.eid) AND x.eid <> y.eid 
AND x.employstatus = 'Active'
WHERE y.employstatus = 'active' 
AND y.Role IN ('SME', 'Junior Team Lead','Team Lead', 'Shift Lead', 'Operations Lead', 'Quality Lead', 'Policy Lead') 
AND y.location = 'manila'),

tbl3 as(
   SELECT x.coachEID,x.CoacheeEID,  sum (x.NoOfApproved) as exempt, x.month, x.year from exemptitems x
LEFT JOIN roster y on y.eid=x.Coacheid
WHERE x.month='1' and x.year='2017'
AND y.eid=x.coacheid and x.NoOfApproved is not NULL
GROUP BY x.CoachEID, x.CoacheeEID, x.Month, x.year),


tbl4 as (
SELECT 
 IIF(tbl2.role is NULL, tbl1.role,tbl2.role) as role,
 IIF(tbl1.coachEID is NULL,tbl2.eid,tbl1.coachEID) as coacheid,
 IIF(tbl1.coacheeEID is NULL, tbl2.coachee,tbl1.coacheeEID) as coacheeeid, 
 IIF(total is NULL,0,total) as total, 
 IIF(tbl2.target is NUll,total,tbl2.target) as ttarget, 
 IIF(tbl3.exempt is NULL,0,tbl3.exempt) as texemption, 
 IIF(tbl2.target is NULL,total,tbl2.target)-IIF(tbl3.exempt is NULL,0,tbl3.exempt) as ttotal
from tbl1
FULL JOIN tbl2  on tbl1.coachEID=tbl2.eid and tbl1.coacheeEID=tbl2.coachee
LEFT JOIN tbl3 on tbl1.coachEID=tbl3.CoachEID
)

SELECT role, coacheid, SUM (total) as totalcoach, SUM (ttarget) as target, SUM (texemption) exemption, SUM (ttotal) total_target from tbl4
GROUP BY role, coacheid
ORDER BY coacheid asc
```

[image: here's the result]

Please feel free to add if I missed out something, but for me it seems to be working pretty fine.